# Regarding the [mount] tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I think it's better to rename [mount](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mount) to [mounting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mounting). It seems like better english usage to me.

Comment: Either way, they should be synonyms. The same goes for `umount` and `unmounting` (and perhaps `unmount`, currently unused); the displayed name should not be `umount` because its meaning is less clear than the English words.

Answer (score 5):

I disagree, since the actual unix command for this is "mount", and it seems useful to have the tag match the command.

Comment: What of less standard utilities like **pmount**? Should I add a tag for it, or in their case, should I stick to [mounting]?

Comment: If it's concerning a specific utility, my opinion is we should have a tag for that utility... as well as the more generic [mount, mounting] tag (:  Not sure what others feel though.  Guess I should hang out in meta more!

Comment: I think mounting is silly. stick to mount, I'm ok with tags for specific utilities. anything else can just be filesystems and kernel.